# Having trouble creating a foreign key in C# using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, postgresql, entity-framework, .net-core

I'm building a simple app using ASP.NET and Entity Framework. I want the user to be able to log in, create a "Character", and display all the characters created on the particular user's account.

I'm using a PostgreSQL database, and in order for the functionality I'm looking for to work, I created a column in the `Characters` table to populate the user id from the `ApplicationUsers` table.

The problem is, I can't figure out how to populate that column with a user id when a new character is created. The character gets created in the `Character` table, but the `UserId` column populates as NULL.

These are my data models:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    [PersonalData]
    [Column(TypeName = "varchar(100)")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [PersonalData]
    [Column(TypeName = "varchar(100)")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    public List<Character> Character { get; set; }
}

public class Character
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string CharacterName { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string Profession { get; set; }

    public string UserId { get; set; }
}
```

These are my tables in PostgreSQL:

[AspNetUsers table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B6TSe.png)

[Characters table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BTBp8.png)

This is my DbContext:

```
public class AuthDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public AuthDbContext(DbContextOptions<AuthDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Character> Characters { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        // Customize the ASP.NET Identity model and override the defaults if needed.
        // For example, you can rename the ASP.NET Identity table names and more.
        // Add your customizations after calling base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    }
}
```

I tried different combinations of things: having only the foreign key tag on the .NET side of things, adding a foreign key constraint to the `Characters` table in PostgreSQL, having JUST the foreign key constraint, adding the following code to the `DbContext`:

```
{
    base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        
    builder.Entity<Character>()
                .HasOne(m => m.ApplicationUser)
                .WithMany(m => m.Character);
}
```

As stated earlier, what I want to have happen is for the `UserId` column in the `Characters` table to be populated with the Id from the `AspNetUsers` table.

Comment: Have you read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships ?

Comment: @JeremyLakeman thank you for the link. I did read the Introduction To Relationships article you linked to and updated my models accordingly. I added the reference to my ApplicationUsers model in my Character model, but it hasn't fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add HasForeignKey() into your modelBuilder:

```
{
    base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    
    builder.Entity<Character>()
            .HasOne(m => m.ApplicationUser)
            .WithMany(m => m.Character)
            .HasForeignKey(m => m.UserId);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I added this, and also tried adding the comparable version for Entity<ApplicationUser>, but it didn't seem to help unfortunately.